# Is < eu > an element in Greek?

Tags: greek

I am pondering the morphological structure of < therapeutic > and < pharmaceutical >. When looking at the Greek roots I can analyze the spelling with the exception of < eu >. I see that < eu > is a prefix in Greek with a sense of “well,” however, I can’t find an analysis of < eu > as a stem suffix.

Comment: Well, it’s definitely a derivative suffix – not related to the prefix meaning ‘good’. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-εύς#Ancient_Greek) has an overview of what types of nouns _-εύς_ forms.

Comment: What do you mean by "element"? It's a diphthong, are diphthongs elements?

Answer (score 2):

-εύω is a standard Greek verb suffix: [denominative](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%CE%B5%CF%8D%CF%89); so [θεραπεύω](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0058:entry=qerapeu/w) (ΙΙ.4) is to heal, to cure, the only meaning surviving today in that language. The τ enters the agentive [θεραπευτής](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B8%CE%B5%CF%81%CE%B1%CF%80%CE%B5%CF%85%CF%84%CE%AE%CF%82#Ancient_Greek), whence the adjective for the property, [θεραπευτικός](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B8%CE%B5%CF%81%CE%B1%CF%80%CE%B5%CF%85%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%BA%CF%8C%CF%82#Ancient_Greek).

It has entered English in the [16th century](https://www.etymonline.com/word/therapeutic). (There is a slippery glitch around the τ in that description.)

---

(Geeky): In case you might care, according to the ultimate expert, Beekes, the  -εύς  ending may well have entered Greek from (non-IE) Pre-Greek,

> Though the ending may also be inherited from lE, in many words it is clearly of Pre-Greek origin, e.g. βασιλεύς (Myc. qa-si-re-u), Ἀχιλλεύς.

Comment: Though of course Beekes attributes practically _everything_ to Pre-Greek even when there are plausible IE etymologies.

Comment: @Draconis Deniably, as here... but yes, his triumphs have entrenched an experiential bias there... Too many nails for the hammer wielder...